# Parallel kinit calls lead to a corrupted Kerberos cache

Tags: kerberos

If I try to authenticate with a Kerberos keytab multiple times in parallel, I randomly get error messages stating that the credentials cache is corrupted.

I could reproduce this problem with the following script. However, in my real use case there are processes calling `kinit` at the same time and I cannot control them :

```
kdestroy
kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && echo "OK" &
kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && echo "OK" &
kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && echo "OK" &
kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && echo "OK" &
kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && echo "OK"
```

Which produces random outputs each time I run it. An example of such an output is as follows :

```
kinit: Failed to store credentials: Internal credentials cache error (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1645005342) while getting initial credentials
kinit: Failed to store credentials: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1645005342) while getting initial credentials
kinit: Failed to store credentials: Bad format in credentials cache (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1645005342) while getting initial credentials
OK
OK
```

Is there a way to make `kinit` "wait its turn" and don't access the cache if it is already being accessed by another process ?

Comment: In that script put a 'sleep' statement in between each line, make it wait 1 -3 seconds between each kinit call.

Comment: The script is there just to reproduce the error. But in my real use case, there are processes calling `kinit` at the same time and I cannot control them

Comment: I see that you are using Unix or Linux.  Are you using the OS version of kinit or the Java kinit?  If Java, what version of the JRE/JDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If multiple processes create tickets independently, then they have no reason to use the **same** credentials cache. In the worst case they would even use different principals, and the side effects would be... interesting.

Solution:  change the environment of each process so that `KRB5CCNAME` points to a specific file -- and preferably, in an application-specific directory. That will prevent race conditions, and clean up your mess.

Partial solution: maintain a single cache, but not based on a file *(since Linux has no way to force an exclusive lock on a file)* e.g. `KEYRING`.

Anyway you are entitled to complain about the sh... er, the clumsy way these apps have been developed. Or maybe they were designed to run in isolated containers ?

Comment: Hello, I'm facing this same issue, can you please provide more info, links or references on how to implement the main solution ?

Comment: MIT Kerberos documentation, environment variables, `KRB5CCNAME`. Make sure it points to a location that is specific to each app instance.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we had to execute concurrent jobs withing the same process. Eventually, used an external file lock to synchronize parallel kinit calls.

```
Begin
…

#Assign unused file descriptor e.g. 99 to a file called “kinit_lock.dat”
exec 99 >”kinit_lock.dat”

#try to acquire exclusive lock for “kinit_lock.dat” with timeout of 5 secs.
flock -x -w 5 99

#Invoke kinit
kinit <parameters>

#unlock the kinit lock file
flock -u 99

…
Job script
…

End
```

Answer (score 0):

[ Solution ]

```
if ! klist -s; then for i in 1 2 3; do kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && break || sleep 2; done; fi
```

[ Explanation ]

I faced the same issue in concurrent environment, so I sorted it using below command by decreasing its frequency and using retry mechanism with sleep of 2 sec:::

> if ! klist -s; then for i in 1 2 3; do kinit $USER@$REALM -k -t $HOME/$USER.keytab && break || sleep 2; done; fi

1. If condition with `klist` will check if the cache is already there or not. If the cache is already present then it will not execute kinit.
2. Retry 3 times if failed after every 2 seconds.