# Limit the usage of Kerberos TGTs

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I'm pretty new to Kerberos. I'm testing the Single Sign On feature using Kerberos. The environment: Windows clients (with Active Directory authentication) connecting to an Apache server running on Linux machine. The called cgi script (in Perl) connects to a DB server using the forwarded user TGT. Everything works fine (I have the principals, the keytab files, config files and the result from the DB server :) ). So, if as `win_usr_a` on Windows side I launch my CGI request, the CGI script connects to the remote DB and queries `select user from dual` and it gets back `win_usr_a@EXAMPLE.COM`.

I have only one issue I'd like to solve. Currently the credential cache stored as FILE:.... On the intermediate Apache server, the user running the Apache server gets the forwarded TGTs of all authenticated users (as it can see all the credential caches) and while the TGTs lifetime are not expired it can requests any service principals for those users.

I know that the hosts are considered as trusted in Kerberos by definition, but I would be happy if I could limit the usability of the forwarded TGTs. For example can I set the Active Directory to limit the forwarded TGT to be valid only to request a given service principal? And/Or is there a way to define the forwarded TGT to make it able to be used only once, namely after requesting any service principal, become invalid. Or is there a way the cgi script could detect if the forwarded TGT was used by someone else (maybe check a usage counter?).

Now I have only one solution. I can define the lifetime of the forwarded TGT to 2 sec and initiate a kdestroy in the CGI script after the DB connection is established (I set that the CGI script can be executed by the apache-user, but it cannot modify the code). Can I do a bit more?

The credential caches should be hidden somehow. I think defining the credential cache as API: would be nice, but this is only defined for Windows. On Linux maybe the KEYRING:process:name or MEMORY: could be a better solution as this is local to the current process and destroyed when the process is exited. As I know apache create a new process for a new connection, so this may work. Maybe KEYRING:thread:name is the solution? But - according to the [thread-keyring(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/thread-keyring.7.html) man page - it is not inherited by clone and cleared by execve sys call. So, if e.g. Perl is called by execve it will not get the credential cache. Maybe using mod_perl + KEYRING:thread:name?

Any idea would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Kerberos itself does not provide any mechanism to limit the scope of who can use it if the client happens to have all the necessary bits at a given point in time. Once you have a usable TGT, you have a usable TGT, and can do with it what you like. This is a fundamentally flawed design as far as security concerns go.

Windows refers to this as unconstrained delegation, and specifically has a solution for this through a Kerberos extension called [[MS-SFU]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/MS-SFU/3bff5864-8135-400e-bdd9-33b552051d94) which is more broadly referred to as Constrained Delegation.

The gist of the protocol is that you send a regular service ticket (without attached TGT) to the server (Apache) and the server is enlightened enough to know that it can exchange that service ticket to itself for a service ticket to a delegated server (DB) from Active Directory. The server then uses the new service ticket to authenticate to the DB, and the DB see's it's a service ticket for `win_usr_a` despite being sent by Apache.

The trick of course is that enlightenment bit. Without knowing more about the specifics of how the authentication is happening in your CGI, it's impossible to say whether whatever you're doing supports `[MS-SFU]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I know how the Kerberos authetication works from the MIT tutorial. I know that MS always do its own tricks. :) So thanks for the 'Constrained Delegation', I did not know about it!
On the other hand CGI itself does not do any authentication, it is done by Apache's `mod_auth_kerb` and it sets `REMOTE_USER=win_usr_a@EXAMPLE.COM` and CGI could use this field. Practically, it does not need to be used, as based on the forwarded TGT it can query from the DB without user name and password (like `sqlplus /@DB_ALIAS`).

Comment: _"This is a fundamentally flawed design as far as security concerns go"_ >> IMHO it's the way application developers manage the cache that is fundamentally flawed. Especially Microsoft Windows devs that made sure you have no easy way to avoid the global LSA cache _(totalitarian principle: "Everything not forbidden is compulsory")_

Comment: Okay? That has nothing to do with this. It doesn't change the fact that you're sending a secret to a remote service that can impersonate you against any other service. You have to trust that service will not do anything malicious with your ticket. As security goes, that's a bad design. Period.

Comment: How ironic that MSFT had to retrofit that "flawed protocol" into Active Directory... for lack of a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217438/5162372) *(to a different question, focused on "race conditions" when updating the cache)*

> If multiple processes create tickets independently, then they have no
>   reason to use the same credentials cache. In the worst case they would
>   even use different principals, and the side effects would be...
>   interesting.
>
> Solution: change the environment of **each process** so that `KRB5CCNAME`
>   points to a **specific file** -- and preferably, in an
>   application-specific directory.

If your focus in on securing the credentials, then go one step further and **don't use a cache**. Modify your client app so that it creates the TGT and service tickets on-the-fly and keeps it private.

Note that Java never publishes anything to the Kerberos cache; it may either read from the cache or bypass it altogether, depending on the JAAS config. Too bad the Java implementation of Kerberos is limited and rather brittle, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html and https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jaas.html

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned I plan to put the credential cache to a session-KEYRING, but I have to define a CCache to be able to use the DB's functions which use Kerberos. So this is not a plain file, but memory in the kernel (not even swapped).