# linux kerberos auth to two domains

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

I need auth to two independet domains on my CentOS7 via krb5. It is possible?
For example when I use login name1 who is in domain1 or when I use login2 who is in domain2.
Logins are unique and are not repeated in domains.
My example conf file is below, I can auth only to default_realm

krb5.conf:

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
 
[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
rdns = false
default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
default_realm = DOMAIN1.COM
dns_lookup_kdc = false
dns_lookup_realm = false

 
[realms]
DOMAIN1.COM = {
  kdc = adc.domain1.com
  admin_server = adc.domain1.com
}
 
DOMAIN2.COM = {
  kdc = adc.domain2.com
  kdc = adc.domain2.com
  admin_server = 192.168.3.24:749
}
 
[domain_realm]
domain1.com = DOMAIN1.COM
.domain1.com = DOMAIN1.COM
domain2.com = DOMAIN2.COM
.domain2.com = DOMAIN2.COM
 
[appdefaults]
pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one "default_realm" in your config. An you are not supposed to have multiple identities at the same time (whether in the same or different realms).

**A.** For client/server applications that have to propagate the client identity, or impersonate the client, you have to manage that in your code (e.g. `doAs()` in Java) and it's not trivial

**B.** For running separate apps with separate identities under the same Linux account, you have to cheat with multiple `krb5.conf` and multiple credential caches, by setting env vars `KRB5_CONFIG` and `KRB5CCNAME` for each app

Comment: Cf. also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207555/parallel-kinit-calls-lead-to-a-corrupted-kerberos-cache

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it. This will be a temporary solution. I think to set default_realm by script with specified login mask from "secure" log file.

Comment: You said you needed to "need auth to two independent domains on my CentOS7 via krb5."  But you didn't say to what service.  You also didn't say what your IDP was - AD?  Red Hat IDM?  Other???  Regardless, I think you're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is [Trust between the two domains.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/using_trusts)

> 11.5.1. A Trust Relationship A trust means that the users within one realm are trusted to access the resources in another domain as if they
> belonged to that realm. This is done by creating a shared key for a
> single principal that is held in common by both domains.

This sounds like it would solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it on test environment, now I'm using script to change default_realm